# Time validation with regex

Tags: shell, solaris, ksh

I'd like to make validation about time stamp of one of my log file. But it seems I have problem on my expression in case statement.

TIME value might be something like 11:49 or 2011. And I just want to check whether it is  HH:MM format or not. Code is in below.
It is always saying year format althought file is in HH:MM format

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
TIME=`ls -lrth  /var/log/*.log |  grep -i upg | tail -1 | awk '{print $8}'`
echo "$TIME"
validation=false
if [[ $TIME != "" ]]
 then
  case TIME in
     "[0-23]+ :[0-59]")
        validation=true
        break;;
  *) echo "Year format";;
esac
fi

echo "$validation
```

Update : I tried "[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]") but validation still return fail.

Comment: mibzer. You put what you call a comment into an anser. You, as the questioner, should confine your comments to **comment** entries (not Answers). When you have new significant data which doesn't easily fit into a comment, just update your answer, and refer to that in you comment.... Re your problem: you are mixing 2 types of expressios: `glob` style expressions  and `regular` expressions.  The bash `case` statement uses regular expressions. You need to remove the "quotes" ... bash regular expressions need to be exposed; not protected by quotes... If you need spaces, just escape them with `\ `

Comment: @Peter.O Thank you Peter and sorry for confusion.

Comment: There is a mistake in my previous comment: `case` uses a `glob` style expression.

Comment: I think you're on the right track using case expressions, but you don't understand the rules of the character class expressions, i.e. `[0-23]` means "only 1 char matching" either 1). the range 0-2 (i.e. 0,1,2) OR 2) the single number number 3, NOT `0 hrs to 23 hrs` as I'm guessing you mean. ---- Inside sq-brackets, each char stands for itself as a match for one char, excepting when the range notation is use as `0-2`. You can use reg expers in this case to get mostly what you want, ie `case TIME in [0-2][0-9]\ :[0-5][0-9])`. Read it one sq-brkt at a time, what ever inside is a single match. GL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you can't check TIME with `[0-23]+ :[0-59]` expression.

There are several ways to do it:

- To split your variable and check each part separately:

```
TIME="06:25" ; 
[[ $TIME != "" ]] && \
[ ${TIME%:*} -le 23 -a ${TIME%:*} -ge 0 -a \
        ${TIME#*:} -le 59 -a ${TIME#*:} -ge 0 ] && echo ok
```

- To check it with common regex, but it will accept some cases of wrong time (like 28:59):

```
"[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]")
```

Comment: please see my below comment.

Comment: your first advice worked thx, but I have one more question what is TIME%:* and TIME#* mean ? . I haven't used them before

Comment: `TIME%:*` delete all symbols after first `:` from the beginning of the variable, `TIME#*` delete all symbols after first `:` from the end of the variable. You can find more detailed explanation here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

Comment: You can be exact with expression matching:  **1.** "normal" regular expression, using `=~`: `[[ $time =~ ^([01][0-9]|2[0-4]):[0-5][0-9]$ ]]`   **2.** [glob expression](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing), using `==`: `[[ $time == @([01][0-9]|2[0-4]):[0-5][0-9] ]]`